# call javascript on changing dropdown value programatically

Tags: javascript, c#

I have a dropdown having n number of items, on selection of a particular item I make a tr visible. This I've done through JavaScript. Whenever a user changes the dropdown value the JavaScript on change event for the dropdown is fired. Till here its fine.

Problem:
When I set the value of the dropdown from my c# code the JavaScript event isn't fired, due to which the tr is not being visible. How can I address this problem???

Help !!!

Edit 1:

> ```
> > ddlInform_Invite_Rating.Attributes.Add("onchange", "GetInviteRating('"
> > + ddlInform_Invite_Rating.ClientID + "','" + txtInform_Invite_Score.ClientID + "');");
> ```

I've done dis in page load. The javascript is called when user changes the value. but when i set the dropdown's value (on page load) the javascript isnt called. I tried using using registerclientscript but that doesnt work as well.

Comment: You are using website ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the above problem by including the following line in my JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {


             $("#<%=ctrl1.ClientID %>").change(function () {
                 //debugger;

                 if ($(this).val() != 0 && $(this).val() != 99) {
                     $(this).parent().closest('td').next().css("display", "table-cell");
                     $(this).parent().closest('td').next().next().css("display", "table-cell");
                 }
                 else {

                     $(this).parent().closest('td').next().css("display", "none");
                     $(this).parent().closest('td').next().next().css("display", "none");
                 }

             }
         );

             $("#<%=ctrl1.ClientID %>").trigger('change');

         }


 );
```

Thanks for all your help anyway.

Answer (score -1):

You can call javascript function by using below code.

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "key", "yourfunctionhere();", true);
```

Comment: since i am setting the value on page load i'm unable to call the Javascript which takes two controls as its argument and since the page is not completely loaded these args are going null.